# Boostrap modal - Jquery .load() not working on cloned object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
     function callback() {
                    var dialog = popup.clone();
                    dialog.find("h4").text("sdds");
                    $('body').append(dialog);
                    dialog.find(".modal-body")
                        .load($(this).data("href"), false, function(responseText, status, req ) {
                            if (status != "error") {
                                dialog.find(".modal-header h4").text(dialog.find("h1").text());
                                dialog.modal('show');
                            }
                            $('#divLoading').removeClass('show');
                        });

                }

                var popup = $("#modal");
                $(document).on("click", ".q", callback);
```

When an element with class "q" on "" is clicked the callback is triggered and modal is shown. But when I click an element inside the "modal-body" with class 'q' callback is triggered but .load() is not working.

Comment: what do u see in console?

Comment: You don't have an error handler (in the question code) so how can you see what the errors are?  You just ignore errors (`if (status != "error")`)

Comment: no messages in console. check DOM. cloned modal is appended to body.

Comment: @freedomn-m .load() is not triggering.

Comment: You're using event delegation and confirmed that `callback` is called - so it being a cloned object is not relevant.  So you can step through your code (or add console.logs) to find the issue - what's `dialog.find(".modal-body").length` `$(this).data("href)` `responseText` (before status check)

Comment: Well "not working" (from the question) is pretty vague.  When you say "not triggering" do you mean it's getting to that point in the code but not hitting your server?

Comment: my guess is you are getting an error back with the Ajax call. Do you see the Ajax request in the developer console?

Comment: @freedomn-m solved the issue. My mistake. I didn't check the value of  "data(href)". It was empty. That's why ".load()" didn't trigger. I need a good sleep ;) Thank you all.

Comment: @epascarello the error was at "$(this).data("href")". There was no such data attribute. But it didn't give any error in the console! Chrome version "Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)" Ubuntu Linux

Comment: It wouldn't give an error as there's no error - `$(sel).data("missing-data") === "")` which is not an error.

Comment: @5r33naDh I removed it, but while your statement may be true, that is sometimes a problem I run across